# Php email form validation, validation not working

Tags: php

Hello so this might be silly question but I am a beginner in php and a want to make an email form with validation and when I click on the button submit it reloads the page sends the mail even if not all the inputs are completed and after the the button is clicked it says that none of the forms have been completed. Would I need ajax to not let that happen ? 
Here is the code you might understand better:
Php:

```
<?php  
$nameErr = $emailErr = $messageErr = "";

$to = 'example@example.com';
$subject = 'Email form test';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST["name"] )) {
        $nameErr = "* Please enter your name";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    }

    if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailErr = "* Please enter your email"; 
    } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
        $messageErr = "* Please enter a message"; 
    } else {
        $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
    }  

$message = <<<EMAIL

$name
$email
$message

EMAIL;

$header = '$email';

if ($_POST['submit']){
mail( $to , $subject , $message , $header );
$feedback = 'Your email has been sent.';
}
}

?>
```

HTML:

```
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
     <div class="name">
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" placeholder="Name" size="50">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="email">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail" size="50">
        <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    </div>
<br>
    <div class="message">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter your message" rows="6"></textarea>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $messageErr;?></span>
     </div>
<br>
    <div class="submit">
       <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button special">
    </div>
</form>    
<p id="feedback"><?php echo $feedback; ?></p>
```

Thank you.

Comment: "*I call mail() no matter what state the form is in - why is it sending email no matter what state the form is in?*". No you don't need AJAX, just don't call the send mail function when you don't want the mail sent...

Answer (score 1):

I have rewritting your code a bit and I think it should be working like this.

```
<?php  

$errors = array();
$to = 'example@example.com';
$subject = 'Email form test';

$requiredFields = array('name', 'email', 'message');

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    foreach ($required as $field) {
        if (!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) {
             $errors[$field] = '* '.$field.' cannot be empty';
        } else if (!test_input($_POST[$field])) {
             $errors[$field] = '* '.$field.' does not meet the validation';
        }
    }

    $message = $name."\n".$email."\n".$message."\n";
    $header = '$email';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        mail( $to , $subject , $message , $header);
    }
    $feedback = 'Your email has been sent.';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) manual. It determines if a variable is set and is not NULL.

```
//Pay attention to ! (negation)
if (!isset($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "* Please enter your email"; 
}
```

To validate the email you can use:

```
if (!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
```